# Image preview not showing after cloning html form tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a nested comment system using html, jQuery, Ajax, and Javascript.    For each reply button, I have created the same input features as the original message, which includes: (1) image preview before upload, and (2) image upload.  I used jQuery clone method to accomplish this.

However, after pressing the reply button and cloning the form, it shows the image preview on the original message rather than on the reply message.

Here is the link to JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/xexejur/edit?html,js,output

Here is the code:

html

```
<form id="form_clone" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <img id="image_Preview" width="100" height="100" />
    <input type="file" onchange="document.getElementById('image_Preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>

<div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default reply">Reply</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '.reply', function(event){
      var form_clone = $('#form_clone').clone();
      var target = $(event.target);
      var isFormAvailable = $('#form_clone', target).length > 0;
      if(!isFormAvailable) {
        $(event.target).append(form_clone);
      }
    });

});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/clone/ it has 2 overloads if you check the docs

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cloneCount = 0;
    var bindFileChange = function (cloneCount){
        let fileInput = $('input[type="file"][data-count="' + cloneCount +'"]');
        fileInput.on('change', function (){
            $(this).siblings('.image_Preview').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
        });
    };


   $("button").click(function(){
       cloneCount++;
       $("#id0").clone().attr('id', 'id'+ cloneCount).insertAfter("#id" + (cloneCount - 1));
       $('#id' + cloneCount).find('input[type="file"]').first().attr('data-count', cloneCount);
       bindFileChange(cloneCount);
   }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="id0" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-count="0">
    <div>
        <img class="image_Preview" width="100" height="100" />
        <input type="file" class="fileUpload" data-count="0">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
<button id="click">Reply</button>
```

I'll update this answer after seeing your js bin. It's updating the image preview because you have an id assigned to it. Id's should be unique. So first off I would remove the id attribute from your `img` elements and also remove the `change` event on your file input, we can bind it dynamically with js later. In order to target the elements with js though we're going to need to keep a count of the replies, `data attributes` are handy for this.

```
<form id="id0" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-count="0">
    <div>
        <img class="image_Preview" width="100" height="100" />
        <input type="file" class="fileUpload" data-count="0">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
<button id="click">Reply</button>
```

Now for the js, you're on the right track incrementing the form's id. We need to apply this to other elements too so we can target them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cloneCount = 0;
    var bindFileChange = function (cloneCount){
        let fileInput = $('input[type="file"][data-count="' + cloneCount +'"]');
        fileInput.on('change', function (){
            $(this).siblings('.image_Preview').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
        });
    };


   $("button").click(function(){
       cloneCount++;
       $("#id0").clone().attr('id', 'id'+ cloneCount).insertAfter("#id" + (cloneCount - 1));
       $('#id' + cloneCount).find('input[type="file"]').first().attr('data-count', cloneCount);
       bindFileChange(cloneCount);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Having `.clone(true, true)` or `.clone(true)` sends the preview image to the original message even though the image name is on reply message if I hover over the image icon.

Comment: If you're deep cloning the original form, it will act exactly the same as the original form. If you don't want that behaviour use `.append()` and specify your markup. You can then rebind events using `.bind()`

Comment: I tried everything.  I just can't figure out how to use `.append()` and `.bind()` in place of  `.clone()`.   Should I use `.clone()` in addition to `.append()` and `.bind()` or should I drop out `.clone()`?

Comment: Sean, I reduced the code to only a few lines and put it on JS Bin.  Can you look at this problem again?

Comment: I've edited, something along those lines will see you right

Comment: I tested the code.  Every time I press Reply button, I get the following error message on Chrome console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined" on the following line: `$('#id' + cloneCount).find('input[type="file"]')[0].attr('data-count', cloneCount);`  I haven't been able to debug it yet.

Comment: There were a couple of typos as it was untested - I've added a working snippet

Comment: I fixed the remaining code myself, so image preview now shows on both the original message and on reply messages.  Here is the link to JSBin:  https://jsbin.com/xexejur/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Sean,  I want to replace Choose File with Camera Font Awesome on the cloned form using your code, but I can't figure out how to bind Font Awesome to the cloned form.  Can you look at my question on Stack Overflow at the following link?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/56959424/4982271