# How image preview can be removed after it is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After I preview an image and submit it, the image still remains there with the message comment added. I want the image preview to be removed automatically once it is submitted.

This is my html code:

```js
 function showPreview(objFileInput) {
      if (objFileInput.files && objFileInput.files[0]) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function (e) {
        $("#targetLayer").html('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" width="200px" height="200px" class="upload-preview" />');
        $("#targetLayer").css('opacity','0.7');
        $(".icon-choose-image").css('opacity','0.5');
        }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(objFileInput.files[0]);
      }
    }

    $("#image_name").change(function(e) {
      showPreview(this);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="targetOuter">
      <div id="targetLayer"></div>
      <img src="photo.png"  class="icon-choose-image"  />
      <div class="icon-choose-image">
      <input name="image_name" id="image_name" type="file" class="inputFile"  />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: how do you submit the image?

Comment: empty() html('') etc

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I tried both `$("#targetLayer").empty();`  and  `$("#targetLayer").remove();`  It didn't work.   Where in the code should I enter it to make it work?  You can see the full code at my question: "Image preview not showing after cloning html form tag" at stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Target the image element and remove 
$(.icon-choose-image).remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!   The image preview is in `#targetLayer`.   So I should enter `$("#targetLayer").remove();`  somewhere in the code.   But where in the code should I enter it to make it work?   You can see the full code at my question:  "Image preview not showing after cloning html form tag" at stack overflow.

Comment: I could make it work by placing  `$("#targetLayer").remove();`  just after the 1st ajax method inside the submit method.  But it also removes the "Comment Added" message.  So it solves one problem, but creates another.

Comment: You can clear the form after submitting. Where is the rest of your code? Can create a codepen, i'll take a look at it

Comment: Thanks!  Here is the link to all the code:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/56654961/4982271        How can I clear the form?

Comment: I entered the code for reset like this, but it didn't help:    `$("#targetLayer").remove();` 
 `location.reload();` 
`});` 
`$("#comment_form")[0].reset();`