# Replacing Choose File with Font Awesome icon makes cloned image preview inoperable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Apparently, I can’t figure out how to bind font awesome element to the cloned form.  I tried everything, but the image on the cloned form goes to the original message.

The image preview was already functioning on the cloned form.  Afterwards First on html, I added font awesome element with camera icon just above `<input type="file"`.  Second on javascript, I added a function to trigger font awesome element, which works on the original message submission.  Third, I created `iClone()` function  to find, trigger, and change the `data-count` number of both font awesome and input file after grabbing font awesome element using jQuery.  Fourth,  I created `var cloneCount = 0;` variable initially set to 0 to increment and change the id name of the cloned form. Fifth, I created `var bindFileChange = function(cloneCount) {` variable to bind font awesome and file input elements to the new form with new form id name.

Next on the reply button `$("button").click(function(){`, where the actual cloning takes place, first, `cloneCount++;` increments cloneCount, i.e., id name of the new form.  Second, it clones the form and add the new id name to it. Third, it runs the `iClone` function. Finally, it runs the `bindFileChange(cloneCount);` function. This is supposed to bind both font awesome and input file to the new form with a new id.  But it doesn't work.

Here is the link to the test case, where I tried to add font-awesome to cloned image preview, on JSBin:  https://jsbin.com/cepanet/4/edit?js

And, here is the link to the functioning code for cloning image preview without font-awesome on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/xexejur/10/edit?html,js,output

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Original message. It is not cloned.
  $("#form_clone0").click('submit', function() {
    let fileInput = $('input[type="file"][data-count="' + cloneCount + '"]');
    fileInput.on('change', function() {
      $(this).siblings('.image_Preview').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
    });

    // Function to activate font awesome
    $("i").click(function() {
      $("input[type='file']").trigger('click');
    });

  });

  // Function to find, trigger, and change the data-count number of both font 
  // awesome and input file after grabbing font awesome element using jQuery.
  function iClone() {
    $("i").click(function() {
      $("input[type='file']").first().attr('data-count', cloneCount).trigger('click');
    });
  };

  // Variables to bind font awesome and file input elements to cloned form. 
  // Including, variable to increment cloned form counter. Set to zero.
  var cloneCount = 0;
  var bindFileChange = function(cloneCount) {
    let fileInput = $('i, span, input[type="file"][data-count="' + cloneCount + '"]');
    fileInput.on('change', function() {
      $('i').siblings('.image_Preview').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
    });
  };

  $("button").click(function() {

    // Cloned functions for reply message.  Actual cloning takes place 
    // here.
    cloneCount++;
    $("#form_clone0").clone().attr('id', 'form_clone' + cloneCount).insertAfter("#form_clone" + (cloneCount - 1));
    iClone();
    bindFileChange(cloneCount);
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="form_clone0">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <div>
        <img class="image_Preview" width="100" height="100" />
        <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
        <input type="file" class="fileUpload" data-count="0" style="display: none;">
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <button>Reply</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of assigning ids to anything if you are using jQuery (especially an icon/button)? Moreover a cloned form? One form can handle multiple file uploads.

Comment: @zer00ne  Each cloned form should have a different id name so the reply message content form does not go to the original message content form.  I removed `id="click"` from the reply button as there is no need for it.  So there is only one id, i.e., `id="form_clone0"`.

Comment: @zer00ne  Can you find a solution to this problem?  Here is the link to the functioning code for cloning image preview without font-awesome:  https://jsbin.com/xexejur/10/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Didn't have time to examine link but I do have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57015542/2813224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a label and assign it `[for]` attribute with the value of the input id:

  ```
  <label for='upload'></label>
  <input id='upload' type='file'>
  ```

  When the label is clicked then the input that it is associated with is as well.
- Delegate events on an ancestor tag that existed since the page loaded. Pass a selector that represents all applicable tags that you want to target to the second parameter (it's called `Event.data`).

  ```
    $('main').on('click change', '.file, .upload, .reply', function(e) {...
  ```
- Cloning becomes complicated if the source being cloned has unwanted content. It may be easier just to clone the contents of a `<template>` or just render a htmlString. The following demo does the latter.
- 99% of the time it's optimal to place all `<script>` tags before the `</body>` end tag (see HTML of Demo).

```js
let count = 0;

$('main').on('click change', '.file, .reply, .upload', function(e) {
  if ($(this).is('.reply')) {
    ++count;
    const htmlString = `<form id="box${count}" class="input-group form-row" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><label class="input-group-prepend" for="image${count}" style="display:block;min-height:120px"><figure class="input-group-text" style="min-height:100%"><i class="btn btn-light fa fa-camera tip" title='Select an image or video file'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img class="preview" width="100" height="100">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<figcaption>&nbsp;</figcaption></figure></label><input id="image${count}" name='image${count}' class="file" type="file" data-count="${count}" style="display: none"><section class="input-group-append" style="max-height: 120px"><fieldset class="btn-group-vertical" style="min-height: 100%"><button class="upload btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" style="min-height: 50%" form="box${count}">Upload</button> <button class="reply btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button" style="min-height: 50%">Reply</button></fieldset></section></form>`;
    $('main')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
  } else if ($(this).is('.file')) {
    $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.preview').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
    $(this).closest('.input-group').find('figcaption').text(this.value.split(`\\`).pop());
  } else if ($(this).is('.upload')) {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
    e.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

$('body').tooltip({
  selector: '.tip'
});
```

```css
i.tip.btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <main class='container'>

    <form id='box' class='input-group form-row' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label class='input-group-prepend' for='image' style='display:block;min-height:120px'>
        <figure class='input-group-text' style='min-height:100%'>
          <i class="btn btn-light fa fa-camera tip" title='Select an image or video file'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <img class="preview" width="100" height="100">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <figcaption>&nbsp;</figcaption>
        </figure>
        </label>
      <input id='image' name='image' class="file" type="file" data-count="0" style="display: none;">
      <section class=' input-group-append' style='max-height: 120px'>
        <fieldset class='btn-group-vertical' style='min-height: 100%'>
          <button class='upload btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='button' style='min-height: 50%' form='box'>Upload</button>
          <button class='reply btn btn-secondary btn-sm' type='button' style='min-height: 50%'>Reply</button>
        </fieldset>
      </section>
    </form>

  </main>

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    <!--This is where the jQuery/JavaScript would be placed-->
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I found problem fully implementing the `htmlString` method of cloning into my program in that in a nested comment system the reply message goes to the original message rather than going under the message that it replies to.  I noticed that in `<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />` inside the `htmlString` form clone, the `value="0"` doesn't change.  It stays zero; however, in a nested comment system it changes.  Do you have any idea what causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I found the solution.  I changed `value="0"` to `value="${comment_id}"`

Comment: The htmlString is a template literal which is a string with extra feature basically, it's also standard. Instead of quotes:`'` or `"`, they are wrapped in backticks:```. The `${...}` is syntax for interpolation. Not only can you interpolate variables you can also interpolate expressions. Also, you don't need a backslash in void elements ex. `<input id='i0' name='i0' type='hidden'>`, or  `<img src='https://i.ibb.co/ZHvWsKb/o1z7p.jpg' alt='Lena'>`

Comment: I add  the check mark.  Thanks!   Now the problem is Bootstrap tooltip inside the `htmlstring` variable does not fully function, i.e., it does not show the background color of black on top of camera icon when I hover over it.  It only shows "Attach a photo or video" at the bottom of the camera icon with white background.   Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: This is the code:  `<i class="fa fa-camera"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Attach a photo or video"></i>`

Comment: Are you using the layout as my answer or is it different?

Comment: Yes, I am using your own layout.  I just added `data-toggle="tooltip"` to the code above.

Comment: I added  `data-toggle="tooltip"` to both the code in html and the `const htmlString` inside jQuery.

Comment: Since each new form is dynamic it's not possible to place event handlers on them. Fortunately BS has the [selector option](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4215) See update

Comment: It fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: That' great. Happy coding!

Comment: Do you know how to add CKEditor to the cloned form inside the `const htmlString`?  I am using your own layout; I just added `<textarea>` to it.

Comment: Hi @Brian I'm afraid that would constitute a separate question. Post a new question and reference this question if need be (you are still required to include the code as you did in this question (good job on this one I might add)). Comment here (start with: `@zer00ne`) and I'll review and answer it if it's within my ability (never used CKEditor but I have some experience with WYSIWYG editors).

Comment: I'll do.  Thanks!